# Trimming arrays to remove whitespace in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write a simple function that can trim whitespaces from arrays. When I call the function the result I get is undefined.

Code below

```
function cleanNames(arr){
  const arrmap = arr.map(function(element){return element.trim()});
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'trim whitespaces from arrays'? I suppose those arrays are containing strings? Please, post some valid input and expected output sample.

Comment: `map` returns a new array. I does not modify the source array.

Comment: Why are you not doing anything with `arrmap`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ES6:

```js
var arr = [' one    ', '    two  ', ' three'];

const trimmer = () => arr.map(el => el.trim());

console.log(trimmer(arr));
```

Comment: @Alex Irabor Glad to help. Please, accept my answer if it helped you. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't return result from `cleanNames()` function.

```js
function cleanNames(arr){
  return arr.map(function(element){return element.trim()});
}

const arr = [' apple', 'peach '];
console.log(cleanNames(arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

you maybe miss the return value of the function

```
function cleanNames(arr){
  const arrmap = arr.map(function(element){return element.trim()});
return arrmap ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Array.prototype.map()** in combination with the trim() method to remove the whitespaces for this.

```js
let arr = ["   Peter ", "   Jon ", " cchris "];
console.log(arr);

let trimmed = trimmer(arr);
console.log(trimmed);

function trimmer(a){
   let trimmedArr = a.map(val => {return val.trim()});   return trimmedArr;
}
```

Comment: Np @alex irabor

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple by running a simple for loop:

```
let arrToTrim = ["  a", "  b  ", "c   "]
   function trimmedArr(arr){
     for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(typeof arr[i] === "string"){
          arr[i] = arr[i].trim();
        }
     }
    return arr;
   }
  trimmedArr(arrToTrim);
```

Answer (score 0):

using forEach loop

```
    var a = [" a ", "b", "c"];

    function cleanNames(arr) {
        arr.forEach(function (entry) {
            console.log(entry.trim());
        });
    }

    cleanNames(a);
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for posting your answer! Please not post raw code snippets as answers. Please add at least some explanation on why and how you think this solves the problem of the question. I recommend editing your post.